# How to parse Json response in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I need to parse out "choices" and save 123347 and save "option" to a string  from the following String:

```
{
"type" : "radiobuttons",
"patient" : false,
"text" : "How are you today",
"id" : 63339,
"position" : 2,


"options" : "123344:ok today;123345:see you tomorrow;123346:call friend;123347:call lisa;",


"required" : true,




"choices" : {
"123347" : {
  "value" : 3,
  "option" : "iOS"
},

"123345" : {
  "option" : "Android",
  "value" : 1
},
"123346" : {
  "option" : "Windows",
  "value" : 2
},
"123344" : {
  "option" : "MAC",
  "value" : 0
}
}
}






let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: str, options: [])
```

Comment: Wich version of swift are you using ?

Comment: I don't think JSONSerialization accepts strings, it does however accepts Data types.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5**

Try to serialize and decode it

```
let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: responseObject as Any, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys)
let customObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(CustomObject.self, from: jsonResponse)
guard let requiredChoice = customObject.choices["123347"] else{
  return
}
 let option = requiredChoice.option
 print(option)
```

CustomObject for your json:

```
struct CustomObject: Codable {
    let type: String
    let patient: Bool
    let text: String
    let id, position: Int
    let options: String
    let customObjectRequired: Bool
    let choices: [String: Choice]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, patient, text, id, position, options
        case customObjectRequired = "required"
        case choices
    }
}

struct Choice: Codable {
    let option: String
    let value: Int
}
```

There are many tools available to easily create struct/class for your json:
E.g: https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: Any reason for "-1"ing?